# CATKIN MAKE ERROR "make -j4 -l4" failed

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, ubuntu, rgbdslamv2, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ubuntu operating system. And I am trying to install and run RGBDSLAM on ubuntu 16.04LTS following the guidelines on this webpage [here](http://felixendres.github.io/rgbdslam_v2/). The installation procedure works fine until I insert the command of catkin_make. This is the error that I received.

```
Base path: /home/adil/rgbdslam_catkin_ws
Source space: /home/adil/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/adil/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/adil/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/adil/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/adil/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/adil/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Built target _rgbdslam_generate_messages_check_deps_rgbdslam_ros_ui_s
[  0%] Built target _rgbdslam_generate_messages_check_deps_rgbdslam_ros_ui_b
[  0%] Built target _rgbdslam_generate_messages_check_deps_rgbdslam_ros_ui_f
[  0%] Built target _rgbdslam_generate_messages_check_deps_rgbdslam_ros_ui
[  5%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages_lisp
[ 16%] Built target siftgpu_proj
[ 23%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages_eus
[ 29%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages_cpp
[ 35%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 42%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages_py
[ 42%] Built target rgbdslam_gencpp
[ 42%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages
[ 43%] Generating src/moc_ros_service_ui.cxx
[ 45%] Generating src/moc_qtros.cxx
[ 46%] Generating src/moc_openni_listener.cxx
[ 47%] Generating src/moc_qt_gui.cxx
usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hp:50: Parse error at "BOOST_JOIN"
rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'rgbdslam_v2-hydro/src/moc_qtros.cxx' 
failed
make[2]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-hydro/src/moc_qtros.cxx] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hp:50: Parse error at "BOOST_JOIN"
rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/build.make:87: recipe for target 'rgbdslam_v2-hydro/src
/moc_ros_service_ui.cxx' failed 
make[2]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-hydro/src/moc_ros_service_ui.cxx] Error 1
usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hp:50: Parse error at "BOOST_JOIN"
rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/build.make:72: recipe for target 'rgbdslam_v2-hydro/src/moc_qt_gui.cxx' 
failed
make[2]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-hydro/src/moc_qt_gui.cxx] Error 1
usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hp:50: Parse error at "BOOST_JOIN"
rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/build.make:67: recipe for target 'rgbdslam_v2-hydro/src   
/moc_openni_listener.cxx' failed
make[2]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-hydro/src/moc_openni_listener.cxx] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3158: recipe for target 'rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

This problem has got me hanging for long time. And I am not able to proceed forward with anything. Kindly advise in this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252434/catkin-make-error-%22make--j4--l4%22-failed/) by [bonzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29118/bonzi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-01-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alessiadele](https://answers.ros.org/users/38779/alessiadele/) on 2018-12-03**:
Hi guys!
I have the same error, and I tried to solve it following the guide in the github issue forum; actually, it didn't work and I don't know why.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"Duplicate" of this [github issue](https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2/issues/47)

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2017-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0